# How to get pointcut context in aspect association?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

So I'm doing some exercises on AspectJ for fun and practice and wanted to implement a memoization aspect since this is one of the most usual use cases.

This included using this annotation

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Memoized {
    String value();
}
```

To which I'd like to pass a `String` representing a `Duration` using ISO-8601 seconds-based representation, so, something like:

```java
    @Memoized("PT1H30M")
    public int memoizedMethod() {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
```

So, for this to work, I have to create an aspect which holds a Guava cache, and use an around advice that uses the method signature as the key and caches or retrieves from cache the result, I arrived at this:

```java
public aspect Memoize pertarget(memoized(Memoized)) {
    private final Cache<String, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).build();

    public pointcut memoized(Memoized memoized) : call(@Memoized * *.*()) && @annotation(memoized) ;

    Object around(Memoized memoized): memoized(memoized) {
        var key = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();

        try {
            return cache.get(key, () -> proceed(memoized));
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This however, doesn't fulfill my needs. As you can see, I'm hardcoding a `Duration` of 1 minute in the cache creation. I managed to capture the `@Memoized` contents in the pointcut, and could use it in the advice to do a `Duration.parse(memoized.value())`, but I need this value at the aspect association, i.e. the `pertarget(memoized())`.

I've read the official documentation but I'm still unsure of what the parameter to the pointcut in the aspect association really means, I just put `Memoized` there because I saw it in an example and wouldn't compile otherwise.

Is there any way I could just capture the `memoized` instance of the annotation there and then use it in the cache instantiation like I can do in the advice?

Comment: What is the rationale behind creating `partarget` aspect instances instead of using the default singleton instantiation model? If this is not your invention, please provide a link to the original code in order for me to understand better.

Comment: If I understood well (I'm a newbie at aspectj), the singleton instantiation model would mean that there would be only one instance of this aspect (and thus of the cache) for any advised methods. What I wanted was one instance for each advised method, with the cache duration specified in the annotation. In hindsight, maybe pertarget isn't valid for this either?

Comment: `pertarget` creates an instance per target object instance and for which the given pointcut matches. If you simply want an instance per control flow, probably `percflow` is the better instantiation model, see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-instantiation). Alternatively, you could stick with the singleton aspect and manage a set of caches, one per method.

Comment: Which instantiation model and aspect implementation you should use depends on the caching strategy you need. Do you need to cache method results per target instance, because target state influences method results? Are the memoised methods more like pure functions which yield the exact same output for the same set of input parameters? That part is not really an AspectJ problem.

Comment: Correcting myself: `percflow` is probably also not what you want, because it would create a new aspect instance not per method but every time the method is executed. I think you should stick with a singleton aspect and make it manage a set of caches, one for each target method.

Comment: Actually I realized I could do with a pertype aspect since the classes I advised are singletons, but I just thought using pertarget would be more flexible (in case I eventually decided to use it on non-singletons). Your solution is fine. Maybe I could just use pertarget with a non-final cache set to null and instantiate it in the advice with the correct duration if it's not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using the wrong cache keys. You should use cache keys which are composed of a representation of method arguments, not method name. Otherwise, you would always get the exact same result from the cache for each method call, no matter which arguments are used.

Here is a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), using a singleton aspect:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Memoized {
  String value();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.aspectj.lang.Aspects;

import de.scrum_master.aspect.Memoize;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      application = new Application();
      System.out.println(application.capitalise("foo"));
      System.out.println(application.triple(11));
      System.out.println(application.capitalise("bar"));
      System.out.println(application.triple(22));
    }

    Aspects.aspectOf(Memoize.class).printCacheStats();
  }

  @Memoized("PT1M45S")
  public String capitalise(String string) {
    System.out.println("Capitalising " + string);
    return string.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Memoized("PT1H30M")
  public int triple(int i) {
    System.out.println("Tripling " + i);
    return 3 * i;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;

import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

import de.scrum_master.app.Memoized;

public aspect Memoize {
  private final Map<String, Cache<String, Object>> caches = new HashMap<>();

  public pointcut memoized(Memoized memoized) : execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(memoized);

  Object around(Memoized memoized): memoized(memoized) {
    String cacheID = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString();
    Cache<String, Object> cache = caches.get(cacheID);
    if (cache == null) {
      cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().recordStats().expireAfterWrite(Duration.parse(memoized.value())).build();
      caches.put(cacheID, cache);
    }
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + cache);
    String args = Arrays.deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
    try {
      return cache.get(cacheID + "#" + args, () -> proceed(memoized));
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      throw new SoftException(e);
    }
  }
  
  public void printCacheStats() {
    caches.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " +entry.getValue().stats()));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added an extra method to the aspect, so we can see some stats on the console. When runing the driver application, we would expect 2 cache misses and 4 hits for each of the two methods. Let us find out what the console log says:

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
Capitalising foo
FOO
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
Tripling 11
33
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
Capitalising bar
BAR
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
Tripling 22
66
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
FOO
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
33
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
BAR
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
66
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
FOO
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
33
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@4ee285c6
BAR
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int)) -> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache@7dc5e7b4
66
String de.scrum_master.app.Application.capitalise(String) -> CacheStats{hitCount=4, missCount=2, loadSuccessCount=2, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=19678400, evictionCount=0}
int de.scrum_master.app.Application.triple(int) -> CacheStats{hitCount=4, missCount=2, loadSuccessCount=2, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=252000, evictionCount=0}
```

Tadaa!